Запуск программы на сайте
Написал сайт, который в числе прочего должен запускать по нажатию кнопки программу (бот для Дискорда), написанную на языке python. Сама программа проверена на моем компьютере и написана правильно, среда python на самом сайте содержит все нужные для работы библиотеки.
Но программа не запускается - при этом до момента запуска всё работает хорошо. Я даже проверял это тем, что предельно упрощал саму программу, и она работает в упрощенном виде.
Вопрос вот в чем - имеются ли какие-нибудь средства, позволяющие получить мне экран терминала при запуске программы с сайта, чтобы я сам мог увидеть ошибки и их исправить, хотя бы понять чего не хватает.
ПС - вроде ругается на Дискорд, т.к. я убирал всё остальное, оставлял только запуск самого бота, а он не запускался

Настройте логирование, запуск бота в блоке try, и предоставьте код.

Я могу проверить "try" сразу весь код, вместе с обьявлением переменных?

Конечно, нет! Не весь сразу. Да вы можете писать в логи значения интересующих  переменных.

Ладно, я почитаю материал по проверке на ошибки (я тоже об этом думал, а при нахождении ошибки чтобы в файл писался код этой ошибки).

Hадо в каждом месте где могут быть проблемы обернуть блок кода в конструкцию try; except.
Если надо проверить значения некоторых переменных то пишите их в лог.
Начните с запуска бота.
Чтоб получить более конкретный ответ выложите свой код.
Мне кажется, ваша проблема с параллельным выполнением кода.
(так ли это, не видя реализацию подтвердить нельзя)

Там 700 строк в коде)

Там вообще какая-то чертовщина - код в том виде, в каком он есть, вообще не выполняется (я проверил это, вписав первой инструкцией после объявления переменных запись строки в файл)

Ну, можно в Google Colab или GitHub код выложить,  а сюда только ссылку на блокнот или репозиторий.

Да, на ГитХабе он есть, сейчас добавлю изменения и вам скину ссылку... Только чур с кода не ржать, я военнослужащий, а программированием увлекаюсь)

Ссылку добавьте в свой вопрос, сюда в комменты её не надо!

В моей локальной системе проблем с параллельным выполнением не было. Да он и запускает параллельно программу на сайте, если она будет предельно упрощена. Но я попробую поиграть с try, как до нормального компа доберусь

Вот смотрите, когда Вы задаёте вопрос у тех кто пытается Вам помочь должна быть возможность воспроизвести проблему, либо надо предоставить значимые фрагменты кода (по которым можно локализовать Вашу проблему). Во втором случае, необходимо приложить трассировку ошибки (в Вашем случае log.txt, соответственно сейчас Вам надо настроить логирование, получить значимые логи). И когда Вы проделаете эту работу сможете задать более конкретный вопрос. Понимаете?

А по-моему всё нормально, вам сайт мой для понимания проблемы не нужен - он тут не причем и нигде больше кроме запуска приложения не задействуется (и оно запускается). Словом, проблема с импортом библиотек, в частности, библиотеки Дискорд, буду дальше смотреть, но оно и понятно было, потому что после импорта вообще ничего не воспроизводилось программой в полном коде

Внезапно, смог решить свою проблему (хотя, это наверно только верхушка айсберга).
Оказалось, действительно программа ругалась на неизвестные ей библиотеки (в частности, "Discord"), выдавала ошибку ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'discord'") (в коде далее показано, как я эту ошибку отследил, находясь на сайте и по сути запуская код с "чужого" компьютера, спасибо пользователю AnnaBazueva - SPAM за помощь). Ошибка, получается, была с том, что по стандартным путям (указанным в переменной окружения 'PATH') библиотеки не находились. Подсказку дал сам сайт, в котором это всё должно запускаться, он работает под Django, соответственно, в аналоге файла wsgi.py содержится команда на добавление нужной директории (я просто скопировал, на первую позицию списка с путями вставляется нужный нам путь, "2.txt" - файл для записи результатов проверки на ошибки).
Сам код:
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/u0000000/data/pyenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages')

try:
    import discord
except ImportError as e:
    f = open('/var/www/u0000000/data/www/her_tam.ru/page/static/prog/2.txt', 'w')
    f.write(repr(e))
    f.close()
else:
    f = open('/var/www/u0000000/data/www/her_tam.ru/page/static/prog/2.txt', 'w')
    f.write('библиотека импортирована')
    f.close()

При запуске моего кода с сайта на чужом хостинге, скрипт полностью работает. Весь остальной код в итоге тоже заработал.
